# Kafka-spring consumer is not reading message

Tags: spring-integration, apache-kafka

> I am sending message on topics and can read same message using kafka console and Java consumer code using main method. But message are not getting read from consumer configuration xml. Please help to resolve this issue. I am using message  int-kafka:message-driven-channel-adapter.
>   spring-kafka version 1.3.0.RELEASE

```
         <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
xmlns:stream="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/stream"
xmlns:int-kafka="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/kafka"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/stream http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/stream/spring-integration-stream.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/kafka http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/kafka/spring-integration-kafka-1.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task.xsd">


           <int:channel id="inputFromKafka">
            <int:queue />
           </int:channel>


           <bean id="zkConfiguration"  class="org.springframework.integration.kafka.core.ZookeeperConfiguration">
    <constructor-arg ref="zookeeperConnect" />
</bean>

<bean id="kafkaConnectionFactory" class="org.springframework.integration.kafka.core.DefaultConnectionFactory" >
    <constructor-arg ref="zkConfiguration" />
</bean>

  <bean id="decoder"
class="org.springframework.integration.kafka.serializer.common.StringDecoder" />
<int-kafka:message-driven-channel-adapter id="messageProcessor" 
    channel="inputFromKafka"
    connection-factory="kafkaConnectionFactory"
    queue-size="${queue.size:1024}"
        concurrency="${concurrency:50}"
    auto-startup="true"
    payload-decoder="decoder"
    topics="${topics:nishant}" key-decoder="decoder" />
     <int-kafka:zookeeper-connect id="zookeeperConnect" 
  zk-connect="localhost:2181" zk-connection-timeout="6000"
    zk-session-timeout="6000" zk-sync-time="2000" />


         </beans>
```

> Consumer Java code

```
              @Component(value = "messageProcessor")
              public class MessageConsumer {
            public void reader(Map<String, Map<Integer, String>> payload) {
            System.out.println("TEST");

             }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems with your configuration.

First your "consumer" and channel adapter have the same bean name (id) `messageProcessor`. With Spring, the last one wins so one definition will overwrite the other.

Second, all that configuration does is dump the messages into a queue channel `inputFromKafka` - there is no connection to your "consumer". Change the bean name and add a service activator (and remove the `<int:queue/>` element from the channel).

```
<int:channel id="inputFromKafka" />

<int:service-activator ref="myConsumer" input-channel="inputFromKafka" />
```

Will route the messages from the adapter to your consumer bean method (assuming the payload can be converted to your required type).

Comment: Thanks Gary.... now all set...My mistake i override the bean... and commented service activator. Just one question I need to process 600000 request I am creating 10 partition and and consumer side i will add concurrency = 10  and executor thread pool-size="50" right now i have one server only..

Comment: Hi Gary. Please can you help me out. Once i read all message from my topic and restart the server it should not start reading messages from beginning... i am not able to find how to implement this in message-driven configuration. Thanks

Comment: You should really ask another question for this rather than piggy-backing on this one. You need to provide an `offset-manager` - see the [kafka-sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/basic/kafka) for an example; it uses Java configuration but the same applies to XML configuration. If you run the sample multiple times, you will see it does not start from the beginning each time.